# Get image data from HttpContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpcontext

I think I already know the answer but I'd thought I give it a shot anyways.

Can I in MVC.NET get information from the html image tag (i.e css class or data attibute) from the HttpContext?

I'm guessing that the context does not know anything about the html but only the request, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you lookup [MSDN HttpContextBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.aspx) you'll get a pretty good answer:

> **HttpContextBase Class**
>
> Serves as the base class for classes that
> contain HTTP-specific information about an individual HTTP request.

So yes you are right - you will only get information about the request sent to your server.

I assume your client *clicks on an image and that triggers a new request*?

If I am right you may **add a clientSide script** which **writes the requested information** in an **hidden input field** and submit a form - **or** you just **pass** the **information** as an **url parameter** to your server!

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.
I'm not triggering on click. I'm actually looping through all images on page load making image versions. I think my solution will have to be a querystring that contains the settings that I would want to have in a data attribute.

Comment: Still don't get you... what client action triggers the new request? and what image versions do you make? sry don't understand!